# SearchView onQueryTextChange ignore previous characters and only use last typed character

Tags: android, searchview

Is there a way to ignore all the previous characters entered, that get passed to  onQueryTextChange until the last character is entered?

For example, if user types S Y M B O L, it performs a query every time every time the character is entered, so it performs 6 queries. I want to cancel the previous 5 queries, and only run the last one.

```
"select * from table where name  LIKE  :searchText || '%' order by name  limit 500"
```

My table has over 700,000 items in it, so the screen takes about a few seconds to be updated, and I would like it to be updated immediately.
If the user types slow, it's ok, but if they type fast, the screen update is very slow.

I am using RecyclerView and query returns LiveData.

I do have an index on this particular column, so that's not the problem.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: yes you can achieve that using `RxSearch` via `.debounce` operator.[this](https://medium.com/@matdziu/using-rxjava-in-searchview-f1d1d5dcb8b7) link may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use onQueryTextSubmit() callback for passing the final typed string

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(
            new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SearchResultActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(QUERY, query);// Perform search task with query string 
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    return false;// triggered every time you type a character 
                }
            }
    );
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `timer` that will be reset every time the user types:

(Let say, if the user types, 5 seconds of no new text will trigger the search, you can adjust the seconds if it too long)

```
CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) { //5000 for 5 seconds
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        //do your searching here
    }
};
```

And on your `onQueryTextChange`:

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
   timer.cancel();
   timer.start();

   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all your code that's querying the database shouldn't be on the UI thread or you may get an ANR message, and it's just not a good UX, instead you should be displaying to the user some sort of progress message/dialog/view.

There are a few different ways to perform this task, it can be done really easily via Jake Wharton's library [RxBinding](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding) all you would need to add is `.debounce(some_number_of_time_units, Unit.specified_time_unit)`

If you don't want to add another dependencies to your codebase you can use a [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) with post delayed as one of the solutions.